# Postman is showing Assertion Error to check array property

Tags: postman, assertion, postman-testcase

This is my JSON file:

```
{
"courses" : [
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "John",
 "location": "India",
 "courses":["java", "selenium"] 
}
]
}
```

When I try to assert the array property, it shows Assertion Error. This is my Testing script:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Test array properties", () => {
  pm.expect(jsonData.courses).to.include("java");
  pm.expect(jsonData.courses).to.have.members(["java", "selenium"]);
});
```

The error report is as follows:

> Test array properties | AssertionError: the given combination of arguments (undefined and string) is invalid for this assertion. You can use an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset instead of a string

But when I am adding the array directly in place of variable `jsonData`, this issue is not appearing. Here is the script:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Test array properties", () => {
  pm.expect(["java", "selenium"]).to.include("java");
  pm.expect(["java", "selenium"]).to.have.members(["java", "selenium"]);
});
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your JSON file carefully.

`jsonData.courses` do not have the value `["java", "selenium"]`

`jsonData.courses` is an array of objects.

then `jsonData.courses[0].courses` is igual to `["java", "selenium"]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have updated the script. But now another error msg is appearing. The error msg is as follows:
'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')'

This is my updated script:
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Test array properties", () => {
  pm.expect(jsonData.courses[0].courses).to.include("java");
  pm.expect(jsonData.courses[0].courses).to.have.members(["java", "selenium"]);
});

Comment: What is the output of ‘jsonData’? The error happens because ‘jsonData.courses === undefined’